# Paste a vCard from UIPasteBoard into Mail

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad

I copy a vcard (included in the bundle) to the general pasteboard as follows:

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"AM" ofType:@"vcf"]; 
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
[[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard] setData:data forPasteboardType:(NSString*)kUTTypeVCard];
```

I would then like the user to be able to paste it into an email. However, Mail does not offer the Paste option when this has been copied to the pasteboard. Am I doing something wrong or does Mail not recognize that pasteboard type?

Answer (score 0):

You can just add it directly to the message like so

```
MFMailComposeViewController *mailViewController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"AM ofType:@"vcf"]; 
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
[mailViewController addAttachmentData:data mimeType:@"text/vcard" fileName:@"AM.vcf"];
mailViewController.mailComposeDelegate = self;
[self presentModalViewController:mailViewController animated:YES];
[mailViewController release];
```

Comment: Thanks, but you are answering a question that was not asked. Additionally, you specify the wrong mime type in your answer - it should be text/vcard

Comment: sorry, I misunderstood your question. I thought you wanted it to be copied on their clipboard and then have them paste it into a MFMailComposeViewController and I have edited the mime.

Answer (score 0):

Everything in your code looks correct, so if Mail will not allow you to paste it, that means that Mail does not support pasting that type.

Edit: try it with a NSDictionary:

```
UIPasteboard *gpBoard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];

NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

NSDictionary *item = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                      data, (NSString *)kUTTypeVCard,
                      nil];

gpBoard.items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:item, nil];
```

Comment: I have figured out that it is indeed possible to paste a vcard in mail as I copied a vcard in another email and pasted it in a new mail. The question is thus not if but how.

Comment: See edit. You might want to try adding code to paste in the working vcard so you can inspect it.

Comment: Write some paste code, paste in that working vcard, then look at in the debugger. Should be revealing.